# Unable to change script path in Packer amazon-ebs

Tags: packer, amazon-ebs

packer --version
1.4.2

I have this code in my json file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xADUb.jpg)

Mt /tmp has noexec on it, I am hardening the AMI..

Even with the remote_path set, the script is still being executed in /tmp

==> amazon-ebs: Running local shell script: /tmp/packer-shell380358367

==> amazon-ebs: /bin/sh: /tmp/packer-shell380358367: Permission denied

When i ssh to the ec2, there is no file in /tmp directory

Comment: The issue was at the machine which was running the packer! 
Fixed

Answer (score 1):

The issue was at the machine which was running the packer! Fixed